# Having a between operator in the inner join where clause

Tags: sql, oracle

Does this query amount to an inner join:

```
select * from a, b where a.start_date between b.start_date and b.end_date;
```

It seems so but I am confused because I always tend to think that an inner join has to have an = operator in the where clause as opposed to a 'between' operator

Comment: In theory this so called semi-cross join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The actual check means nothing to the join other than ensuring proper association and not brining in all results.

Answer (score 1):

use JOIN instead of , separated tables

the same condition with join looks like this

```
select * from a
JOIN b ON  a.start_date between b.start_date and b.end_date;
```

Comment: Both will return the same set of results (and I think even the same query plan), so this is really a matter of preference, however from a readability aspect, most people do find the join syntax is a bit more readable.

Comment: @user2366842, it is NOT a matter of prefernce, implict joins (the comma ones) have several problems that using exlicit joins avoids such as accidental cross joins. Explicit joins are easier to understand the intent which makes them more maintainable (Was that cross join in there on purpose or by accident, you can tell with explicit joins, you cannot with implict joins). Since all major databases now support explicit joins, there is no reason not to use explicit joins and several reasons not to use implict joins.